# Why IntelliJ has inspections for generic usage disabled by default?

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea, intellij-inspections

Why does IntelliJ has inspections for generic usage disabled by default?

These inspections (`Java 5 -> Raw use of parametrized class`) needs to be enabled explicitly and I find that new developers do not know about them. Is there some good reason I do not know why using raw types would be a good practice?

Comment: Are you talking about the "Raw type can be generic" inspection? That's the only inspection with the word "generic". It's enabled by default though...

Comment: @Sweeper Sorry, I forgot to add, is is called Raw use of parametrized class, it is under Java 5 branch.

Comment: You can set your default in `File->New Project Settings->Settings for new Projects...`.

Comment: @Slaw Maybe, to be honest I do not know, we use either Maven or Gradle and rarely anybody looks at raw `javac` log output. I have it enabled and I always have to point these things in PRs.

Comment: @daniu Yes, but why it is disabled by default? Problem is not me, problem is that other developers do not see yellow warnings all over their code by default.

Answer (score 0):

The `Raw use of parameterized class` inspection is [enabled by default](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175539) since IntelliJ IDEA version 2019.3. Are you using an older version?